# MS Access Pass Form Through Function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a function that will allow me to use various command buttons without having to recreate the code every time.

To do this I have to pass the form name through a function

Function:

```
public Function NewRecord(controlForm, focusForm)
focusForm.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRecord
controlForm.SetFocus
```

controlForm - This is the main form akin to the Me function

focusForm - This is for not only the main form but when I create subforms I have to have the focus on the subform to have the command work.

To call the function I did the following:

```
public sub Command19_Click()
Dim controlForm
Dim focusForm

Set controlForm = Forms![frm_Sales_CustomerProfile]
Set focusForm = Forms![frm_Sales_CustomerProfile]

Call NewRecord(controlForm, focusForm)

End Sub
```

I get this error that States: Compile Error: Invalid Use Of Property.

Comment: Your error is because you call the porperty `NewRecord` of a form! That happens if you don't use strong names.Try `MyModulname.NewRecord(controlForm, focusForm)`. Your second form argument is obsolte. If it's a subform just pass the subform reference. You can access the mainform with `frm.Parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got trapped using an already in this context (the form) used identifier and not using a strong name (NameOfLibrary.NameOfFunction).`NewRecord`is a forms property, so`Invalid Use Of Property`makes sense. If you use`MyModulName.NewRecord(frm1,frm2)`everything is fine. If you use`NewRecord`in Module òr Class it works too as there is no property with same name (I assume;-)).

To be honest, I don't use strong names either (except on database or recordset objects, as I got trapped there too, assuming DAO, using ADODB), but the Pros suggest that and now we know why!

Your function should have just one argument as it is sufficent to pass only the subforms reference if you need that form `NewRecord(frm as Access.Form)` (note the strong name!). You can easy refer to the mainform with Set `mfrm = frm.Parent`

Your code;

```vb
Public Function FrmNewRecord(frm As Access.Form)
    frm.Recordset.AddNew
End Function

Public Sub Command19_Click()
    FrmNewRecord(Forms![frm_Sales_CustomerProfile]) ' mainform
    FrmNewRecord(Forms![frm_Sales_CustomerProfile]!sfrmControl.Form) ' subform
End Sub
```

You are passing the same form two times in your code, any reason? If `Forms[frm_Sales_CustomerProfile]` contains Command19 use `Me`.
I dropped the `.SetFocus`part as not necessary or any reason to for setting focus? Why is NewRecord a function? Doesn't return anything.
btw: I am working on a`SubForms(frm)`function , that returns a collection of all subforms.

Code:

```vb
'SubForms(frm As Access.Form) returns a collection of all subform references in frm

Public Function SubForms(frm As Access.Form) As VBA.Collection
Dim ctr As Access.Control
Dim sfrm As Access.Form
Dim col As New VBA.Collection

For Each ctr In frm.Controls
    If ctr.ControlType = acSubform Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sfrm = ctr.Form
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            col.Add sfrm, sfrm.Name
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next ctr
Set SubForms = col
End Function
```

Comment: I am no sure I am following you.

I see why you want to use the hard names but I don't understand the integration process you suggested. I will have 2 sub forms nested and including the main for that 3 total. Each one needs a new record button. I thought making a function where I can easily reference the new record command would be easier.


I think that I am asking is how do you set up the hard names. I have never used them before so its a bit new to me.

Comment: What is a hard name for you? `controlForm`? It's a variable with the pointer to the form object after it is set, like var for.`Forms![frm_Sales_CustomerProfile]`what is just `Forms.Item("frm_Sales_CustomerProfile")` where Forms is the collection of all forms, specified by its name as key. If it's the first form you can use `Forms.Item(1)`accessing the collection by the index.

Comment: Okay just to make sure I understand. I was pass the one with Item through the function and reference it though the variable name.

Comment: Yes just like you did before with your 2 objects. If you prefer to pass mainform and subform, just add anther form object as argument to the function. I just skipped the assingment to `controlFom`and `focusForm` because you don't need to do that, but you can.

Comment: I tried it out `Private Sub Command19_Click()` then set the variable `Dim control form`. Set the variable `Set controlForm = Forms.Item(frm_Sales_CustomerProfile)` and called the function `Call NewRecord(controlForm)`. The function is the same as before but i have one variable `Public Function NewRecord(controlForm)` and changed the variable for the index `controlForm(1).SetFocus` and `controlForm(1).SetFocus`. I still get the property issue. Did I not do it right?

Comment: Back at start ;-) If you don't rename the function as I did, you have to call it with module name or it assumes you want to use the forms property! A Form has no index as it is no collection. Note the difference: the Form- Object is in the Forms-Collection (plural indicates the collection) the Control in Controls(the collection),Workbook in Workbooks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155772/discussion-between-bitaccesser-and-jake).

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule to build say custom menu bars, or ribbons, you can write code that is “form” neutral like this:

Public Function MyDelete(strPrompt As String, strTable As String)

```
  Dim strSql        As String
  Dim f             As Form
  Set f = Screen.ActiveForm
  If MsgBox("Delete this " & strPrompt & " record?", _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel, "Delete?") = vbYes Then
```

So note how we don’t need to pass the form name at all – the above code simply picks up the active screen as variable “f”.

At that point you can do anything as if the code was inside the form.

So

```
Me.Refresh    (code inside the form)
```

Becomes

```
f.Refresh
```

So the key concept here is that you don’t need to pass the current active form since screenActive form will enable you to get the current form object anyway.

However, for sub forms and “common” type of code the above falls apart because screen.ActiveForm will return the main form, and not the sub form instance.

So as a second recommended approach, simply always pass the current context form object “me” like this:

```
Call MySub(me)
```

And you define your sub like:

```
Sub MySub(f as form)
```

Now in this code we can reference "anything" by using "f" in place of "me"

```
f.Refresh
```

So just pass “me” if you ever use sub forms. Given the above information, then your code becomes:

```
public sub Command19_Click()

   Call NewRecord(me)


End Sub
```

And NewReocrd becomes:

```
Sub NewRecord(f as form)
```

Now in your newreocrd code, you can use “anything” form the object such as:

```
f.Name    ' get name of the form.
```

or

```
City = f.City    ' get value of city control
```

So pass the “whole” form context.

And you could say make a routine to display the City value for any form like:

Call ShowCity(me, "City")

And then

Sub ShowCity(f as form, strControlToShow as string)

```
   Msgbox "City value = " & f(strControlToShow)
```

So OFTEN one will write code that works for any form by simply picking up the current active form as:

```
  Dim f             As Form
  Set f = Screen.ActiveForm
```

And note how the above code picks up right away the active form – this is a good idea since then if focus changes, the “f” reference will remain intact for the code that follows in that “general” routine that is called + used from many forms.

However due to the sub form issue, then often it simply better to always pass the “whole” forms instance/object with:

```
Call MyNewRecord(me)
```

And then define the sub as:

```
Sub MyNewReocord(f as form)

   DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, f.Name, acNewRec
```

End Sub

And you could optional add “focus” to above with

f.SetFocus

So for a lot of menu or ribbon  code, you don't pass the form object, but simply use screen.ActiveForm, and you can also use Screen.ActiveControl (again great for menu bar or ribbon code to grab what control has focus). However due to sub form limitations, then often passing "me" to the routine will achieve similar results if not better in some cases.

Comment: I won't rely on`Screen.ActiveForm`if I can pass the reference . Just like `ActiveSheet`in Excel it can lead to unexpected results. `DoCmd`is ugly too (except open or close form/report). I would prefer `frm.Recordset.AddNew`.

Comment: I suggested passing form reference as fall back position. However screen.Activeform has been a “mainstay” of Access applications for 20 years. Menu bars, tools bars, and now the ribbon works exactly the same for BOTH BUILT in options or code that you write. So you would have to suggest to everyone here to NEVER use any built in option in Access! You can’t make that solid case else you have to suggest to NEVER use any ribbon options – even the built in ones! So some caution and "quirks" is warranted but as “general” advice to avoid screen.Activeform is NOT a general rule nor general advice.

Comment: I never claimed that! But if I can use a more reliable refernce to an object , I use it. If I need `Screen.ActiveForm`I use it, but if not I prefer the reference!